# Proof verification on basic induction, proof/stylistic recommendations

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Could someone please verify my proof of the following proposition? I'm new to induction so beyond the verification of my proof I'm also looking for stylistic pointers/suggestions.

> **Proposition.** For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n (8i-5) = 4n^2-n$$

$Proof.$ We use proof by induction.

*Base case.* For $n=1$ observe that $(8(1)-5)=3$ and $4(1)^2-(1)=3$ so our original equation is true for $n=1$.

*Induction step.* Let $n=k\ge1$. Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^k (8i-5) = 4k^2 - k$. We will show that $n=k$ being true implies $n = k+1$ is also true. Observe that

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}(8i-5)&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(8i-5)+(8(k+1)-5)\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}(8i-5)\right)+(8(k+1)-5)\\
&=(4k^2-k)+(8(k+1)-5)\\
&=4k^2-k+8k+8-5\\
&=4k^2+8k+4-k-1\\
&=(4k^2+8k+4)-(k+1)\\
&=4(k^2+2k+1)-(k+1)\\
&=4(k+1)^2-(k+1) \end{align*}$$

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (8i-5) = 4(k+1)^2 - (k+1)$. It follows by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n(8i-5)=4n^2-n$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Perfect! Just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: the summation should start with $i = 1$ and not $i = 0$. In the *base case* $n = 1$ I would rather write $$\sum_{i = 1}^n \left( 8i - 5\right) = 8 \cdot 1 - 5 = 3 = 4 \cdot 1^2 - 1 = 4n^2 - n$$ The brackets are confusing.

Now the *induction step*. I would stick to the variable $n$, $n+1$ rather than $k$ and $k + 1$. I do not see, why this would be better with a index change. Suppose, the proposition holds for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then we show that it is also true for $n+1$. The rest is fine (perhaps I would omit the second equality, because it is unnecessary to just add brackets).

Comment: Actually I think the point (and the *only*) reason to change index for n to k is to make it clearer and less confusing to students.  And in my opinion that justifies *EVERYTHING*.

Comment: That is a good point. Maybe I am too used to such proofs, that it is hard to explain it perfectly to a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: We never taught it this way in my day.  So *EVERY* effing time I got to the induction step and said.  "Now let's assume you know this is true for some n", I'd get the question "wait isn't that what we are trying to prove?"  So I'd say "we're trying to prove it for all cases.  Right now we are only assuming it for a specific case."  And then "but how can we assume specifically if we don't know generally" and I'd "well we know it for 1"  "but you aren't assuming it is 1"... saying "let's assume it is true for some *k*" saves a lot of headaches. It's not nesc. But it's easier to teach!

Comment: I will be assistant for a subject in the next semester at my university and I will definitely remember this brilliant thought. However, besides from teaching I will use the more rushed version. Thanks again.